# Aws S3 cp will not run through r system function (windows) -- Unable to locate credentials

Tags: windows, r, batch-file, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a batch file that looks like the following (call it "awsCopy.bat"):

```
"C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\Aws.exe" s3 cp "s3://xxxs3bucketxxx/file.csv" "\\networkDrive\folder\file.csv"
```

When I run this batch file it works perfectly, copying my file from s3 and downloading it to my specified directory. (I have run AWS configure already to store my keys in the .../user/.aws/config file).

When I try to run the batch file from R with `system("awsCopy.bat")`, however, the command completes with status 1, does not copy the file and I get the following message:

Unable to locate credentials
Completed 1 part(s) with ... file(s) remaining

I've tried adding set commands in the batch file to no avail:

```
set aws_access_key_id = xxxxxxx
set aws_secret_access_key = yyyyyy
```

Has anyone else had (and solved) this issue? (I'm running windows 7) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the system documentation (on a language I have no idea what it is) on Windows, System does NOT invoke the shell (unlike Unix). It says to use the shell command.

Or in other languages we could use your system call like so (but the docs say use System2 call as it's easier)

```
cmd /c "c:\somedfolder\batch.bat
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I finally figured out the issue. I was executing this script from a network drive, but my credentials were set up only on my local machine. (I guess the setting the keys was just re-setting them locally.) Saving "awsCopy.bat" locally does the trick. Running system, shell and system2 on the batch file path all work.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the issue. I was executing this script from a network drive, but my credentials were set up only on my local machine. (I guess the setting the keys was just re-setting them locally.) Saving "awsCopy.bat" locally does the trick. Running system, shell and system2 on the batch file path all work.